# I need my code to only accept float values

Tags: python, if-statement, input, floating-point, decimal

```
def check_datatype (data,datatype,message):


        if datatype == "Float":
            if not data:
                if not data:
                    print(message)
                return False,data
            else:
                return True,data


check = False
while not check:
    some_text = input('Input a float: ')
    check,a_float = check_datatype(some_text,"Float","You must input a number")
print(a_float)
```

I've tried using `.isdecimal` but it is not working
(If not `data.isdecimal`) This second part of the code is correct but the first part is wrong somehow.

Comment: How is `datatype` defined?

Comment: `if type(datatype) == float:`

Comment: You mean you have a string and you want to check if it is not a whole number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other users suggested, `isinstance` is very helpful in these situations.

Your code should look like this:

```
def funct(data: float) -> (bool, float):
    isFloat = False
    if isinstance(data, float):
        isFloat = True
    else:
        print("message")
    return (isFloat, data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.isinstance()` to get `True` of `False` if the value is defined type.

```
value = 5

print(isinstance(value, float))

# Returns False
```

In your if statement:

```
if isinstance(value, float):
    print(value, "is float")
elif isinstance(value, int):
    print(value, "is interger")
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `if isinstance(datatype,float):` instead of `if datatype == "Float":`